# My BIOS is gone

Tags: boot, bios

After GRUB replaced my MultiBoot Menu and I couldn't change my Boot Device, I got sick of it and opened nautilus and deleted the /boot folder, and I thought doing that would make it go and let me open my BIOS.

It failed ultimately, and pressing the keys to open my BIOS froze my computer and did nothing. Just waiting for something to happen without pressing F2 or F12 opened up a screen that said the GRUB folder couldn't be found and a command prompt type screen with the prefix "grub rescue" without the quotes, and I'm not sure what to put there, and I even googled for information. Before deleting the /boot folder, I made an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS from my Ubuntu 13.04 installation and it is bootable on other computers except mine.I gave up and removed my HDD temporarily so I could see what would happen if I booted without it.

My BIOS would not load and pressing F12 took me to the MultiBoot Menu where only Slimtype DVD and Intel PRO PXE Rom showed up. Attempting to boot from flash drives froze my computer and CDs were the only thing I could load, and CDs would only load when my HDD wasn't in my computer. Is my BIOS actually on my HDD? And how can I fix it? I have a Lenovo B570 Laptop/IdeaPad and its BIOS is PhoenixBIOS Setup Utility.

Comment: Your BIOS is definitely not on your hard drive. It's on a chip on your motherboard. Are you sure you're pressing the right key...?

Comment: You are not pressing the right key. See http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/a/biosaccess_bios.htm

Comment: That was rich... no deleting grub doesn't mess up your bios

Comment: F2 and F12 are the only buttons that do functions when the computer starts up. F2 opens the BIOS, and F12 opens the MultiBoot Menu. Nothing else works, I tried. And I thought it was on my HDD because when I removed it temporarily, pressing F2 or F12 froze my computer and I had to do a cold shutdown.

Comment: Sounds like your BIOS is corrupt, was corrupt, which was the reason you couldn't change your boot device.

Comment: @Ramhound if his bios was corrupt he wouldnt even be able to load grub rescue.

Comment: @MistressDavid - Feel free to explain the reason BIOS froze when he accessed it.  I can guarantee it wasn't anything he did.

Comment: @ramhound 1. Deleting the boot folder should not have trashed the bios 2. He can load OS's just fine 3. The POST should have caught a corrupt bios

Answer (score 3):

You are not pressing the right key. The key for `PheonixBIOS` is supposed to be <kbd>Del</kbd>. For older computers it's supposed to be <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + Esc</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl + Alt + Ins</kbd>, or <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + S</kbd> For more information, see [here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/a/biosaccess_bios.htm). And besides, it's impossible for the BIOS to be on your HDD. It's always on a separate chip. It's possible that you're not pressing the BIOS key at the right time - press it a couple of times as soon as the computer starts.

Comment: Mine is a Lenovo, and nothing, not even DEL bring up the PhoenixBIOS. F2 an F12 are the only keys that alter the way my computer starts up, and they've always been that way. Pressing them without my HDD freezes my computer and nothing happens. I tried everything.

Comment: Try inserting a flash drive /cd and hold shift as your computer boots. That should send you into the grub boot screen.